# Building a Mobile Device: Possible to use XHTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: c++

I'm building a general mobile device that will operate on Ubuntu x86. Is it at all possible, and decently scored in performance, to build said system from  HTML/CSS/Javascript? I'm currently a frontend and backend web developer and designer. At this point, I'm writing the device in C++, but was thinking about converting it into a HTML/CSS/JS/Webkit combination.

It's very, very early stage (I'll have to rewrite probably 10 lines of code, literally) and is very graphics-based.

My device is kind of complex: it's a social messaging device that communiciates over wifi.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Clarification: there will be a C++-based foundation device API that will allow stuff to communicate to the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did when I got hold of Google phone G1 was to  write Tetris clone on Adroid. Although not impossible, it'll be hard to write something like that with timer, graphics, and event handling just using XHTML/CSS/JS.

Would you be providing API to the device itself, like saving data, via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. I just clarified my question — there will be an underlying C++-based framework that will handle device APIs.